# Need help in remove a repository and uninstall its program

Tags: apt, uninstall, brightness, repository

I just added a repository and installed a program by using the following commands in terminal:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

But then I realized that I don't need this as I have certain shortcuts on my keyboard to control screen brightness. So I want to undo these actions. Please help me in removing the repository and uninstalling the program.

P.S. I am new to Ubuntu. So a general method of removing any repository and uninstalling a program will be helpful.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Regarding removing a PPA we already have this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed Removing a PPA also removes software installed by that PPA.

Comment: Simply uninstall as any other software package and remove it in **Software Sources** after that